# PHP Include two files

Tags: php, include

New to PHP and having a problem with a page that has two included statements.

I have one file that has my database connection code and another that has code to list information from the database.  The code in the DB connection file runs fine but the code in the second one does not.

To test I have pulled out all the database stuff from the second file and just left a bunch of echo statements but that code still does not run.

I put the "Testing1" and "Testing2" in the main page for troubleshooting.  "Connection to MySQL server successfully established" and "Testing 1" are shown when the page is loaded but nothing else.

Main page

```
  <?php include 'db.php';?>
<html>
<Head>
    <Title>
        Tracked Items
    </title>
</head>
<body>
  Testing1<br>
<?php include 'ListAll.php';?>
  Testing2<br>
</body>
<?php $conn->close(); ?>
</html>
```

db.php

```
<?php
  $host_name = 'xxxx';
  $database = 'xxxx';
  $user_name = 'xxxx';
  $password = 'xxxx';

  $link = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

  if ($link->connect_error) {
    die('<p>Failed to connect to MySQL: '. $link->connect_error .'</p>');
  } else {
     echo '<p>Connection to MySQL server successfully established.</p>';
  }
?>
```

ListAll.php

```
<?php
echo "<b>Current Items</b><br>";
echo "<Table border=""1"">";
echo "  <tr>";
echo "      <td width=""300""><b>Description</b></td>";
echo "      <td width=""80""><b>Date Opened</b></td>";
echo "      <td width=""80""><b>Last Action Date</b></td>";
echo "      <td width=""750""><b>Last Action</b><td>";
echo "</tr>";
?>
```

Comment: Are there any errors/warnings/etc. in the PHP logs?  Have you enable PHP error reporting to display errors on the page?  What is the exact resulting page source in the browser?

Comment: Try `require` and see if you get a warning about wrong path

Comment: Changed include to require and did not see a change.

Comment: Not sure how to tell if PHP error reporting is enabled.  Site is hosed by third party.

Comment: It might be that it already has error _logging_ enabled then, if it's an internet-facing server. So there's likely to be a file named `error_log` or something similar in the hosting account, which would store PHP errors. If you're not sure, asking the hosting company what the configuration is. Most people test their code on their local machine first though, before deploying it to a hosted environment. You can use tools such as XAMPP or Laragon to install a full-featured PHP and MySQL environment on your own machine, which generally makes the development process quicker and easier.

Comment: Have a look at [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). You could also look for a decent programmer's editor or IDE (PhpStorm, VSCode, Notepad++) which has at built-in syntax checking or at least highlighting, so that you're not coding blind.

Comment: An `include` doesn't need to include PHP. https://3v4l.org/Jk6Ov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the double double quotes.

And it reports the error as

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected double-quoted string "1", expecting "," or ";"  ......

when you find your error log these should be in there.

So either use single quotes for the attribute values inside a double quoted string like this

```
echo "<b>Current Items</b><br>";
echo "<Table border='1'>";
echo "  <tr>";
echo "      <td width='300'><b>Description</b></td>";
echo "      <td width='80'><b>Date Opened</b></td>";
echo "      <td width='80'><b>Last Action Date</b></td>";
echo "      <td width='750'><b>Last Action</b><td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

OR single quote the echo and use double quotes for the attributes, and of course only one set of double quotes

```
echo '<b>Current Items</b><br>';
echo '<Table border="1">';
echo '  <tr>';
echo '      <td width="300"><b>Description</b></td>';
echo '      <td width="80"><b>Date Opened</b></td>';
echo '      <td width="80"><b>Last Action Date</b></td>';
echo '      <td width="750"><b>Last Action</b><td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

To get errors out of PHP *even in a LIVE environment* add these 3 lines **temporarily, while debugging**, to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

If you are using PHP < 8.0, to get errors from the `mysqli_` extension also add

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors. In PHP 8 or greater, this is the default for MySQLI calls.

Comment: Third alternative: escape the double quotes: `echo "<Table border=\"1\">";` I wonder if the OP was actually trying to do that with the `""1""`, which is how it's often done in CSV files.

Comment: Replacing "" with ' did the trick.  Thank you.

Comment: @IMSoP You can, personally I never would as it makes code almost unreadable :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Indeed, just thought it might be worth including for the sake of completeness. There are other contexts where it's the most reasonable compromise.